# How can I get post list on WordPress (only title ,date and time)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Please how can I get post title and I want to list it 20 post in one page and there will be next button please help me

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => 20 // Number of Post you Want in a page
  'paged' => $paged // Tells the current number of page in query
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args ); // adding custom query

   while($custom_query->have_posts()) :
      $custom_query->the_post();
 the_title(); // Getting and printing the title of POST/Page

        endwhile; 
       if (function_exists("pagination")) {
          pagination($my_query->max_num_pages); // Calling pagination 
      } ?>
```

Comment: describe your answer.

Comment: Where should I add this code should I create a custom blog template and add the code there

Answer (score 0):

You can do just like @Asad said. To add his code anywhere download the plugin Woody Ad Snippets in the Wordpress repository:

https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php/

And add the PHP code into a Universal Snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''paged'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ')' in /home/woloade1/public_html/wp-content/plugins/insert-php/includes/shortcodes/shortcode-universal.php(53) : eval()'d code on line 5

I got this error